# PHP only coming out with code

Tags: php, configuration

I'm honestly not sure exactly what is going on here. I'm teaching myself php and I think I've finally gotten the server working, but now I have more questions. When I plug in the code, I should get a single output. In this case, it should just come out with "hello world." Instead I literally get this:

```
<?php
echo "hello world";
?>
```

I'm pretty sure that's not supposed to happen. If I put in the HTML code, it will do exactly the same thing, but with the html code as well. Someone in a chat room mentioned I might have a php configuration problem, but after following another set of instructions online it appears I have nothing wrong.

I'm using OSX 10.7 with the onboard apache server, and I'm testing in Google Chrome. Also, I have to have very specific instructions on how to do something in Terminal since I also have very little formal computer training and therefore have no idea what I'm doing.

Edited: Turns out my files weren't allowing me to access them. A friend showed me how to alter the files so I could view them properly. It was an obscure problem and required a somewhat obscure solution.

Comment: Sounds like PHP isn't installed, or Apache isn't aware of it.

Comment: You php parser is not installed, or you dont use .php for you php files.

Comment: Make sure PHP is installed, and are you using the `.php` extension?

Comment: If you put HTML in the file and have no PHP code it still shows the HTML tags as well??

Comment: BenM, I'm using the `.php` extension, but that doesn't seem to do much. Mike and John, how do I install php? Is there something special I have to do to install it?

Comment: cryptic, yes. The HTML tags show up as well.

Comment: @KimberlyLewis if that is the case, you may be having a combination of problems, one being the mimetype is being sent as text/plain, otherwise a file with just HTML content should not show the HTML tags, they would be rendered.

Comment: How do you call your web page? What is in your address bar of your browser? Something like file://C:/My Documents... or maybe http:// 127.0.0.1, http:// localhost ?

Comment: It is already installed, it just isn't turned on in Apache itself.  If you look at the link I provided you'll see how to turn it on for Apache.

Comment: Voitcus, It's coming from http:// localhost, and then the extension I plugged in. I'm using Aptana Studio 3 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [page](http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/).  By default Apache in Lion does not have PHP enabled so you'll need to change the configuration so you can use it.

Comment: Have you restarted Apache since the change was made?  In Lion you'd find it in System Preferences/Sharing/Web Sharing.  Or try a reboot.

The relevant parts of that link is the section on Apache.

Comment: Yup. Restarted Apache a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, PHP is not enabled!

Open terminal and type!

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Remove '#' before (You can use search)

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

Save the conf file and you should have it!

Comment: What about these lines (its Windows server though, //// is a newline) 
AddType text/html .php .phps ////
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php ////
<FilesMatch \.php$> ////
      SetHandler application/x-httpd-php ////
</FilesMatch>

Comment: I can't find those unfortunately.

Comment: Can we see your php.ini file:
> cd /private/etc 
> sudo cp php.ini.default php.ini

Comment: What do you need to see in it? I can get there, I just need to know what so I can find it (I think). Namely because literally nothing comes up when I check.

Answer (score 0):

In my Apache for windows I have

```
LoadModule php5_module "C:/Program Files/PHP/php5apache2_2.dll"
PHPIniDir "C:/Program Files/PHP"
AddType text/html .php .phps
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

On any other system it should look alike except paths to files.

Take a look what Nab Raj wrote. After completing it might be needed to restart server. These lines are to say to Apache that it is going to give PHP files that have extensions of .php